# Tip of the shoe prevents unclipping with crank rotated to the rear

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes, clipless

I recently got some Crankbrothers Mallet E pedals (standard cleats) and Shimano MW7 shoes for winter. Now I noticed that when I try to unclip with my rear foot the crank arm (Truvativ Stylo 6K, Boost) collides with my toes and locks me in place.

Tried to move the cleats to the front/inside with 15° release angle. This did not solve the problem.

Is this just a bad shoe/pedal/crank combination or should I try something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can’t you unclip with the foot in the 6 or 12 o'clock pedaling position? Can you install the cleat with some rotation (so you don’t have to rotate your feet/shoes as much to release)? Have you maybe installed the cleats very far towards your heels?

Comment: Cleat position/angle on the shoe should be set up for foot position, not for easy of unclipping (@Michael) to avoid injury

Comment: @Michael If I tilt my toes downwards I can unclip without colliding with the crank arm, but this does not seem feasible in emergency situations.

I will try rotating the cleats. But this will reduce the float angle.

The cleats are positioned quite far towards the toes.

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes of course, but with some pedal systems it doesn’t affect foot position and merely changes release angle.

Comment: I'm not much of a mountainbiker, but do run SPDs on my hardtail, at least when riding solo.  I almost always unclip near a 6 o'clock position, occasionally 12 o'clock.  If I'm standing on horizontal cranks, that's not the time I want to be unclipping - I'd rather unclip earlier and ride with my mid-foot on the pedal if I feel the need (but my pedals are more suited to that than yours).  Based on road experience, unclipping at the back of the stroke feels wrong like a wrong movement, especially as the foot has  inherently got weight on it

Comment: @Michael if there's a lot of float, you mean? ±3° seems common on MTB cleats, which doesn't leave much to actually float if you use it up biasing the unclipping angle

Comment: @ChrisH correct, the cleats have a float angle of 6°.

Unclipping at 6 or 12o'clock works fine, but this is not what I usually do with flats. I'm used to keeping my crank near horizontal if  I'm not pedalling.

Comment: @reciprocallettuce horizontal cranks are of course a good thing (unless of course you want your outside foot down).  You're probably more skilled and faster than me, so my solution of unclipping when I've got time to move my feet may not be a solution for you (hence commenting rather than answering with it).  Just looking at the soles of my shoes I'd have no hope unclipping in that position, except, have you tried twisting your heel inwards? It might hit the back wheel of course so take care

Comment: I think I’ve never even tried unclipping with horizontal cranks. And I’ve done cyclocross. Not sure it’s actually a use case.

Comment: I don’t think changing to a different pedal/crank will help; they don’t vary in dimensions thatttt much. I suppose you could buy the long spindle kit to bring the pedals out from the crank a little more. Perhaps the MW7 are really just that thick.

Comment: But long spindles would affect your leg/hip angle which can cause all kinds of problems. Of course it depends on your specific anatomy.

Comment: @Michael MTB setup is usually a little less picky regarding Q-factor. Different hub spacings, chainlines, cranks, etc all have different Qs. Except for at the pointy end of competition, most people seem to be able to adapt between 142mm hubs vs 148mm vs 157mm. I'll have to experiment with horizontal unclipping when I get home today -- Pretty sure I can do it (albeit with XC shoes). I can definitely see the appeal for clipping out off-road.

Comment: Are the cleats **tight**?  If they can move just a bit, unclipping can be a lot harder.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Cleats are tightened to 4 Nm.

Comment: @Michael I tried adjusting the cleat angle just a little and it almost works now. I am going to try out some other cleats with lower release angle and post a self answer if that solves the problem. (It probably will)